# Smarty Compiler: Syntax error in config file

Tags: php, syntax-error, smarty, php-8.2, smarty-plugins

ERROR

```
Uncaught  --> Smarty Compiler: Syntax error in config file 'example.conf' on line 1 '# Column names of example'  - Unexpected "# Column names of example", expected one of: NEWLINE <-- 
  thrown
```

file:- example.conf
Mycode

```
1.# Column names of 
2.
3.SREQUEST_DEPARTURE="Departure"
4.SREQUEST_CAPACITY="Capacity"
5.SREQUEST_SOLD="Sold"
```

My smarty version 4.3.1 , PHP version 8.2

If the first line is empty, then this error occurs.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how are you editing this conf file?  Do you have a BOM in this config file?